# Get Inbound Change Set Details

Tags: event, change-set, einstein-analytics, setup-audit-log, monitoring

I would like to get details about an inbound change set. I already know that I can get its name and Request ID through Event Monitor and only its name through Setup Audit Trail, but I would like to get (I need to use it at Wave Analytics) information about what the Change Set contains.

Answer (score 3):

You can download outbound changeset using workbench.

1) Go to [Salesforce Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/) , Then **Migration** -> **Retreive**

2) Put the exact name of changeset in Package names and tick **Single Package** then Next , Retreive.

It will download the outbound changeset as a zip file with all the changes you want.

Src: [My Blog](http://itsrainingcloud.blogspot.com/2016/08/how-to-download-salesforce-chang.html)

Comment: And is it possible to get information about an Inbound Change Set? Is through metadata the only way? because I want to show it on analytics

Comment: I can't find a way to do that for inbound changeset. If you want for analytics it makes sense to use a custom tool like gearset.com